# jqueryui button enable doesn't render as enabled

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a button:

```
<div class="button-row">
  <div class="create">Create</div>
  <div class="advanced">More Options</div>
</div>
```

This code DOES work to enable or disable the button, but it doesn't remove the disabled classes, so it looks disabled:

```
function enableClickButton() {
   clickEnabled = !(hour_value == "0" && minute_value == "0");
   popup.find('.create').button('option', 'disabled', !clickEnabled);
}

popup.find('.create').button().click(
... other code here.
```

The classes "ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" remain set on the button. It doesn't even work to try to force this, with or without button(), even if I put it on a timeout.

```
popup.find('.create').button().removeClass("ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the button was not rendered yet. Moving the code a few lines down to the render handler solved the problem.